# Due to the rain the children didn't go out an play

Tags: commas

Should it be:

> Due to the rain the children didn't go out and play.

Or

> Due to the rain, the children didn't go out and play.

This question has come up before, but I can't find an answer that includes an explanation of introductions saying why. I don't know what sort of phrase it is.

I think the latter.

Comment: can anyone explain why this is opinion based, i have no idea?

Comment: ok i've got nowhere, thanks for letting me know @BenjaminHarman i will either learn the exhaustive list of different reasons for parenthetical commas, or just use them however i feel

Comment: i have no idea if that's just because i am using a different but legitimate terminology, or not

Comment: that doesn't seem to me to cover the example @BenjaminHarman

Comment: it's clearly your terminology. sorry, i didn't mean to imply it was just yours, if that was the issue @BenjaminHarman

Comment: doesn't [this link](http://guidetogrammar.org/grammar/combining_skills.htm) say that an introductory modifier can be a parenthetical? "There is no true verb in an absolute phrase, however, and it is always treated as a parenthetical element, an introductory modifier, which is set off by a comma"... i'm just suggesting that while my terminology may not be the most helpful, it may also be reasonable (not that you're wrong)

Comment: i mean the chompchomp introductions handout does not seem to "cover the example" @BenjaminHarman

Comment: ok that's cool, i'll wait for someone to link to the question @BenjaminHarman thanks